# NodeGit checkout a branch but Get error "HEAD detached at origin/branch"?

Tags: node.js, git, github, nodegit, node-github

I am using nodegit to checkout from clone and Open it to do something.
My code like this:

```
//repo is a Repository from Clone() or Open()
//branchName is your branch name, of course
repo.getBranch('refs/remotes/origin/' + branchName)
    .then(function(reference) {
        //checkout branch
        return repo.checkoutRef(reference);
    });
```

But after that I cd in to branch directory and typing the command like this

```
git status
or git branch
```

It's show a red line like this

```
HEAD detached at origin/branchname
```

How can I solved it?
Thanks

Comment: What's the value of `reference`? It should be `branchname` only. `refs/heads/branchname` or `origin/branchname` or `refs/remotes/origin/branchname` lead to a detached HEAD.

Comment: The value of ref (reference) is: refs/remotes/origin/branchname

Comment: But if i cannot checkout specific branch by nodegit, do you know another way? I cannot do like that: "return repo.getBranch(branchName);", so I have to do with: "return repo.getBranch('refs/remotes/origin/'+ branchName);"

Comment: I'm completely new to node.js. Is it possible to run something like `return repo.checkoutRef(reference.replace('refs/remotes/origin/', ''))` in Python? The method is to replace `refs/remotes/origin/` with the empty string. A more reliable way is some method corresponding to the command `git checkout -b branchname refs/remotes/origin/branchname`. BTW, a detached HEAD is not an error.

Answer (score 1):

In general,<sup>1</sup> `origin/somebranch` is not a *branch* name, and therefore `git checkout origin/somebranch` results in a detached HEAD, exactly as you are seeing.

Branch names, in Git, don't really do any good, to a first approximation.<sup>2</sup>  So there's no need to use them.  To understand how and why this is the case, let's note that in Git, there are *many kinds of names*.

A *branch name* is simply a name which, when spelled out in full, begins with `refs/heads/`.  The branch names `master` or `main`, for instance, are really `refs/heads/master` and `refs/heads/main`, correspondingly.

A *tag name* is a name which, when spelled out in full, begins with `refs/tags/`.  So `v2.1` is really `refs/tags/v2.1`.

Git calls these things—these names in general, before they're split into some particular classification—*refs* or *references*.  Each reference holds one (1) hash ID.  The hash ID is what really matters to Git.  That's what Git *needs*.  That's what `git checkout` requires: a hash ID.  You can give it any valid commit hash ID, and it will check out that commit.

Hash IDs, though, are big and ugly and *look* random (though they're not).  They are thoroughly unmemorable.  What commit is `225365fb5195e804274ab569ac3cc4919451dc7f` anyway?  If I say `v2.31.0-rc0`, that probably means something—or at least, seems suggestive of something—to you; but if I say `2253blah` you have probably forgotten the `2253` part long before I get to the `dc7f` part.  So *refs* are for *humans*.  They're not for Git, which only really cares about the hash IDs.

You only need a ref—such as a branch name—if you're a human.  If you're a build system, a hash ID is fine.  If you're writing part of a build system, just use a hash ID.  If you're writing something for a human to use ... well, humans are *hard*.

Git has a special thing it calls "DWIM", or Do What I Mean, mode.  If you run:

```
git checkout foobranch
```

and *there is no branch named `foobranch`* right now, Git will assume that you mean: *Find me a name that **resembles** `foobranch`, such as `origin/foobranch`.  Then use that name to **make** a branch name for me.*  You can *disable* this with `git checkout --no-guess` and sometimes that's a good idea.  But sometimes this DWIM mode is exactly what you want.

Note, however, that if the pesky human went and made *his own* `foobranch` earlier, not related to `origin/foobranch`, this `git checkout foobranch` will get *his* `foobranch`, not related to `origin/foobranch`.  So be careful: humans are tricky and weird.  They do illogical, unexpected things.

Now, there's a reason humans often want to use a *branch* name, rather than any other name that results in the detached-HEAD mode.  The primary reason they like this is because then, if they make a *new* commit, Git will *change the hash ID stored in the branch name*.  The new commit will automatically link, backwards, to whatever commit *was* the one stored in the reference.  Then Git will update the *branch name* so that it now stores the hash ID of the *new* commit.

This feature is exclusive to *branch* names.  No other kind of name has this special feature.  You *can* select detached-HEAD mode when using a branch name, by running `git checkout --detach foobranch` for instance.  But the *default* is that when you use `git checkout` with a *branch* name—even one that DWIM mode is going to have to *create*—Git will instead go into *attached HEAD* mode.<sup>3</sup>  So that's why humans like branch names, and that's what Git does with them, that it doesn't do with any other reference name.

If you need to accommodate humans, you can do that by letting the DWIM mode do its thing here.  That won't satisfy *all* humans, so watch out.  It also won't work in some cases, so watch out.  The detached-HEAD mode always works, though.

[In NodeGit specifically, you have `Branch.create` as an async class method of `Branch`.](https://www.nodegit.org/api/branch/#create).  You also have [`Branch.lookup`](https://www.nodegit.org/api/branch/#lookup).  You could use this to look up a remote-tracking name, like `origin/branchname`, and use that to create a new local branch, if that's your goal.  But as before, watch out for all these various edge cases.

---

<sup>1</sup>It is possible to make a (local) branch named `origin/somebranch`, so that it *is* a branch name.  The result is very confusing unless you carefully call out all names using their full spellings.  Don't do this!

<sup>2</sup>Of course, they *do* do some good, so the first approximation is pretty rough.

<sup>3</sup>Git does not call it this, but what else could the right phrase for "opposite of detached HEAD" mode be?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a new local branch with name is same with remote branch to check out it. I will try Branch.lookup() as you recommend.